# how does fully connected layer called fc3 have 20x125 weights

Tags: caffe

According to my calculations, the pooling output should 5x4x4 (5 feature maps of size 4x4) and so flattening it would yield a 1x80 vector. therefore the fc3 should have weights 20x80 but pycaffe shows the layer having 20x125 weights. here is the prototext file. here are my calculations

the equation is use is (dimension_size - kernel)/stride + 1
conv1: 1x5x26x26
pool1: 1x5x12x12
conv2: 1x5x10x10
pool2: 1x5x4x4

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 1
  dim: 28
  dim: 28
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "fc3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 20
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc3"
  top: "fc3"
}
layer {
  name: "drop3"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc3"
  top: "fc3"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc4"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc3"
  top: "fc4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "softmax"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc4"
  top: "softmax"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that for max pooling caffe rounds up the output size rather than truncate if it is a fraction. therefore it produces incorrect shapes. the problem has been reported on GitHub but is yet to be resolved to due to backward compatibility problems.